# Make left and right div 100% height of the viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set `height:100%` on the divs, but it's not working. What is the problem there? Can anyone help me please?

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 47px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #364150;
  border-left: 1px solid #3d4957;
  max-height: none !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  left:0px;
}
.right {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set `height` to all the parent containers.

```
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Updated - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvJpyM

You could also use [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), such as `vh` to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

% `height` can only be height of "something", so you must set the `html` and `body` heights, in order to set the % height for elements inside :

```
html, body{
  background-color:black;
  height: 100%;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try change container to position absolute:

```
.container { position:absolute; }
```